# Controlling an electrical motor with my laptop

Tags: usb, control

I want to control an electrical motor with my laptop, I want to start with the following:

- a mini server connected through WiFi to my laptop
- I want to connect an electrical engine to this mini server
- with my laptop I want to be able to control the speed of the engine (lets start with two speed levels, 50% - 100%)
- written in python

I'm a complete beginner in electrical engineering, I do have a few years of experience in web development, so that's a start.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

- is python a good choice?
- what components do I need (motor, laptop, power source etc)?
- is this idea advanced or really basic?
- any good tutorial websites?

As I said im complete new in this field, so I don't even know how I should Google this. I think this is great way to develop my skills and great fun of course.
Please tell me if I need to be more specific.

Thanks in advance for your advice

Comment: Please add more specifications. What kind of motor/engine ? What is the purpose of it? You can find arduino setup with speed ctrl shield and connect it to usb and control it via some kind of serial protocol you implement.

Comment: I'm always bad at guessing. By motor, do yo mean something like this: http://library.solarbotics.net/pieces/pix/tpm.jpg or more like this: http://www.memax.nl/content/images/nieuwe-dutchi-15-kw-electromotor-400v-50-hz-730-rpm_2329_1.jpg

Comment: thanks for your comment, I was think of an engine like this (http://www.conrad.nl/ce/nl/product/205731/Graupner-GRAUPNER-COMPACT-345Z-111V-72-148-V-omwmin-per-Volt-900-turns), for now there is not a real purpose of the engine, as a first step I want to be able to control the speed of the engine. Default speed = 0%, speed 1 = 50%, speed 2 = 100%.

Comment: yes jippie, something like your first suggestion :)

Comment: is it brushed, stepper or brushless motor ?

Comment: English datasheet'like page http://www.graupner.de/en/products/7739/product.aspx

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the Frimata project. http://firmata.org/wiki/Main_Page It mentions Python on the download page ... I'm planning to experiment with it myself, but haven't come around it yet. Arduino is a great platform for experimenting and starting out in controlling electronics. http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Products

Comment: can someone point me to appropriate tutorials, recommend books and or websites? I know I have to start at the beginning

Comment: @Gossamer , the engine I pointed to is brushless.

Comment: http://zedomax.com/blog/2010/06/18/arduino-101-arduino-for-dummies/

Comment: You should indeed drop by in chat, but I'm about to leave right now. Check this room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering it's usually a welcoming and informal place.

Comment: Don't accept the first answer so fast, give it a day so other people can have a look at your question and provide different views on it. Accepted questions get a lot less attention than unaccepted ones.

Comment: okay, good advice :)

Comment: Also, i would suggest to modify the question according to our comments so it is more clear for others who will be reading this afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions are as follows

- is Python a good choice?

  ```
  You want to implement a wifi webserver and want to connect your circuit with it. Some computer front end is must. 
  Python can be a good choice if you are using Linux to implement front end. For Windows, 
  Defiantly, C# or VB.net is a good choice because it will help you to implement very good 
  computer front end GUI with less effort
  ```
- What component you need?

It depends on your circuit. You can check [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) for built in shields and examples 
        (definatly power supply, motor and Laptop or some Desktop Computer is must)

- is this idea advanced or really basic?

  ```
  Can be Advance if you try this with non-supported devices and can be basic if you try this 
  with some per-built libraries or with arduino, as every thing is developed already.
  ```
- Any Good Tutorial Website?

Already mentioned [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/). You can check examples from these website and ofcourse. google is your friend ;)

best of luck

Comment: thanks for the extensive answer! Arduino is indeed the direction i'll be heading to. cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

For the brushless motor you would like to control you need:

- Motor itself (needless to say but still)
- Electronic speed control unit for brushless (ESC)

Most of the time ESC can be controlled via PWM, so you need micro controller which will feed that ESC with pwm. In your case 0%, 50%, 100%, but ESC pwm is used for RC models and have range of 13% duty cycle for 0 to 20% duty cycle for 100%. It is calculated from 20ms pulse which is feed to RC input and 1.5ms-2ms range.

- Microcontroller 
  I suggest you take Arduino as it is easiest to find examples on net for RC/PWM.

Of course you need power supply...

Comment: 'n% duty cycle' is in my experience a more common term than  'n% pwm'.